# Django Form with many to many relationship

Tags: django, django-forms

I am new to django and trying to learn how to create a django form, I created a custom form and everything is working. But I want to create a many to many relationship, the user should be able to input many different items, by adding multiple custom entries for example a user may enter multiple tags for a photo, similar to how stackoverflow works with tags. If the entry the user input already exists, then the database entry should user the existing entry otherwise it should create a new entry.

How is this done?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the most powerful django tagging solution is [django-tagging](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/) see [here for a quick howto](http://theironlion.net/archive/simple-django-tagging-howto/). It uses [generic relations](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/generic_relations/) which is one of the most powerful django feature.

Comment: Cool, would this be the recommended way to implement any many to many relationship that has many possible user inputs. For example if a user was putting in a recipe and I wanted the ingredients to be shared database entries between different recipes?

Comment: generic relations allows you to add fields to any model without modifying your database schema. Its especially useful for creating generic and reusable django apps.
You can also implement your own Model.ManyToManyField that will be rendered as multi-select combo in your forms.